# How to prevent prettier to break single line into multiline?

Tags: visual-studio-code, prettier, prettier-vscode

I have written a single line of code.

[image]

And after save prettier reformat the line into 2.

[image]

How to stop prettier from breaking lines into two?

Answer (score 7):

**You need to increase the `printWidth` in your `.prettierrc` file:**

The number is the number of characters before a wrap will be attempted, to stop lines from being wrapped at all set a high number like `1000`.

`.prettierrc`

```json
{
    "printWidth": 1000
}
```

[From the prettier documentation](https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html)

> Print Width:
> Specify the line length that the printer will wrap on.

Comment: That won't work, it will cause Prettier to try and make all lines 1000 characters long. Ideally they should add a setting that will leave line lengths alone.